# extract string variables defined in an array based on pattern

Tags: arrays, bash

Special parameter "$@" contains the following string variables,

echo $@ 
outputs: a.bdf, b.bdf,c.nas,d.nas

I want to extract the string variables with extension 'bdf' and save it in another array. 
Is it possible to do so in bash?

Comment: it should help: [bash: how to delete elements from an array based on a pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3578584/bash-how-to-delete-elements-from-an-array-based-on-a-pattern)

Comment: _"$@ outputs: a.bdf, b.bdf,c.nas,d.nas"_ I see both `,` and ` ` (_space_) between values. Are the `,` being part of the data or only separators?

Answer (score 1):

Just iterate through it with a for loop :

```
for ARG in "$@";do
    if [[ "$ARG" == *.bdf ]];then
        BDF_ARRAY+=("$ARG")    #you don't need to initialize this array before the loop in bash
    else                       #optional block, if you want to split $@ in 2 arrays
        OTHER_ARRAY+=("$ARG")  
    fi
done

echo ${BDF_ARRAY[@]}
echo ${OTHER_ARRAY[@]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using for loop

```
for i in "$@";do
    if [[ "${i##*.}" == bdf ]]; then
        ARRAY2+=("$i")
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

In the generic *case*:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in "$@"; do
    case "$i" in
        *.bdf)  BDF_ARRAY+=("$i")
                ;;
        *.nas)  NAS_ARRAY+=("$i")
                ;;
    esac
done

for i in "${BDF_ARRAY[@]}"; do echo "BDF: $i"; done
for i in "${NAS_ARRAY[@]}"; do echo "NAS: $i"; done
```