# How to filter a bash array

Tags: bash

Suppose I have a bash array

```
X=("a" "b c" "-d" "k j", "-f")
```

I want to filter by whether starting with `"-"` and get
`("a" "b c" "k j")` and `("-d" "-f")` respectively.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: [Use `getopts`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16483119/example-of-how-to-use-getopts-in-bash) to parse arguments.

Answer (score 11):

I think you'll have to iterate through the array:

```
$ X=("a" "b c" "-d" "k j", "-f")
$ for elem in "${X[@]}"; do [[ $elem == -* ]] && with+=("$elem") || without+=("$elem"); done
$ printf "%s\n" "${with[@]}"
-d
-f
$ printf "%s\n" "${without[@]}"
a
b c
k j,
```

Answer (score 5):

From an [answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58331643/14269772), you could do this:

```
A=$((IFS=$'\n' && echo "${X[*]}") | grep '^-')
B=$((IFS=$'\n' && echo "${X[*]}") | grep -v '^-')
```

From that answer:

> The meat here is that IFS=$'\n' causes "${MY_ARR[*]}" to expand with newlines separating the items, so it can be piped through grep.
> In particular, this will handle spaces embedded inside the items of the array.

We then use `grep` / `grep -v` to filter in / out elements matching the pattern