# Delete some entries of a list or array in bash

Tags: arrays, bash, list, command-line, remove-if

I want to apply a function, of Python, to all files in sub-directories of a given directory.

In bash, `.sh` file, I list all files like so:

```
dir_list=()
while IFS= read -d $'\0' -r file ; do
dir_list=("${dir_list[@]}" "$file")
done < <(find give_directory_Here -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d -print0)
```

However, there are some directories with a pattern, lets say the pattern is `unwanted_pattern`, in their name that I want to remove from `dir_list`.

How can I do that?

I tried things in here which did not work for me:
[solution 1 from stack over flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3578584/bash-how-to-delete-elements-from-an-array-based-on-a-pattern)
or
[solution 2 from stack exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/328882/how-to-add-remove-an-element-to-from-the-array-in-bash), so on!

Comment: The first line mentions Python, but I see nothing else about Python here, and the meaning isn't clear. Would it be as accurate if you just edited that out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Delete some entries of a list or array in bash

Just loop and match:

```
   result=()
   for file in "${dir_list[@]}"
   do
     if [[ "$file" != *"unwanted_pattern"* ]]
     then
       result+=("$file")
     fi
   done
   dir_list=( "${result[@]}" )
```

However, this is the answer to your [XY question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and not the thing you should be doing.

The smarter way would be to not add them in the first place by adding such a check to your loop, and the even smarter way would be to just have `find` exclude them:

```
find give_directory_Here -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d ! -path '*unwanted_pattern*' -print0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, about the XY thing, if I had not done this way, people would have said "what did you try?", "it is not reproducible", etc. :) And, on top of that, now I learned two things with 1 question :D